Why are my anchor links are not working (Ionic)?
This page is built using a CMS (Pimcore). I placed some anchor links on the page to get the user from section to section more easily, but they do not seem to be working consistently, and I don't know how to fix them.
https://donatos.com/global-menu2
Our site uses Ionic, wondering if that is the issue, and if so, what the workaround may be. The links are not part of an unordered list.
I've tried having one of our developers look at this and he's not sure what the problem is, either. The browser I used for testing is Chrome for Mac. I would expect anchor links to work like they typically do... pretty basic functionality IMO!
    <h1 style="text-align: center; display: block;">Explore Our Menu</h1>

<div style="background-color: #ffffff; border: 2px solid #f0efed; border-radius: 8px; padding: 10px; position: sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */ z-index: 1000; top: 4px; text-align: center; width: 90%; display: table; margin: auto; max-width: 100vw;"><a class="anchor" href="/global-menu#pizzas">Pizzas</a><a class="anchor" href="/global-menu#subs" style="white-space:nowrap;">Subs</a> <a class="anchor" href="/global-menu#calzatos">Calzatos</a> <a class="anchor" href="/global-menu#wings">Wings</a> <a class="anchor" href="/global-menu#appetizers">Appetizers</a> <a class="anchor" href="/global-menu#salads">Salads</a> <a class="anchor" href="/global-menu#desserts">Desserts</a></div>

<div id="pizzas" style="margin: 40px 0 0 0; padding: 0; display: block; width: 100%;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Pizzas</h2>
</div>

<div class="menu-item-section"><!-- PEPPERONI -->
<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Pepperoni-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold ">Pepperoni</span><br />
Loaded Edge to Edge&reg; with crispy family recipe pepperoni and aged smoked Provolone, Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- END PEPPERONI --><!-- SERIOUS CHEESE -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2023/08/07/Serious-Cheese-Menu-Image-NO-WC-LOGO-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Serious Cheese</span><br />
Comes with extra cheese built in! Loaded Edge to Edge&reg; with real aged smoked Wisconsin Provolone, Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- END SERIOUS CHEESE --><!-- THE WORKS -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Works-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">The Works</span><br />
Family recipe pepperoni and sausage, freshly cut green peppers and yellow onions, fresh mushrooms, smoked Provolone, Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- END THE WORKS --><!-- SERIOUS MEAT -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Serious-Meat-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Serious Meat</span><br />
Family recipe pepperoni and sausage, shaved ham, ground beef, hardwood smoked bacon, smoked Provolone, Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- SERIOUS MEAT --><!-- FOUNDER'S FAVORITE -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Founders-Favorite-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Founder&#39;s Favorite</span><br />
Family recipe pepperoni and sausage, shaved ham, banana peppers, smoked Provolone, Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- END FOUNDER'S FAVORITE --><!-- VERY VEGY -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Very-Vegy-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Very Vegy</span><br />
Freshly cut Roma tomatoes, green peppers and yellow onions, fresh mushrooms and baby spinach, green olives, smoked Provolone, Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- END VERY VEGY --><!-- MARIACHI CHICKEN -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2023/02/07/Mariachi-Chicken-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Mariachi Chicken&reg;</span><br />
Sliced chicken breast, freshly cut Roma tomatoes and jalape&ntilde;o peppers, smoked Provolone, mariachi spice and a side of sour cream.</div>
</div>
<!-- END MARIACHI CHICKEN --><!-- MARIACHI BEEF -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Mariachi-Beef-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Mariachi Beef&reg;</span><br />
Ground beef, freshly cut Roma tomatoes and jalape&ntilde;o peppers, smoked Provolone, mariachi spice and a side of sour cream.</div>
</div>
<!-- END MARIACHI BEEF --><!-- HOT HONEY PEPPERONI -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2024/08/28/19506926_Hot-Honey-Pepp-Pizza-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Hot Honey Pepperoni</span><br />
Family recipe pepperoni, smoked Provolone, fresh mozzarella, crushed red pepper and Mike&#39;s Hot Honey&reg;</div>
</div>
<!-- END HOT HONEY PEPPERONI --><!-- HOT CHICKEN -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2023/02/07/Hot-Chicken-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Hot Chicken</span><br />
Crispy hot chicken, smoked Provolone cheese, jalape&ntilde;o peppers, Romano, finished with dill pickles and a Ranch drizzle.</div>
</div>
<!-- END HOT CHICKEN --><!-- HAWAIIAN -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Hawaiian-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Hawaiian</span><br />
Shaved ham, pineapple, sliced almonds, cinnamon, smoked Provolone.</div>
</div>
<!-- END HAWAIIAN --><!-- CHICKEN SPINACH MOZZARELLA -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Chicken-Spinach-Mozzarella-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Chicken Spinach Mozzarella</span><br />
Sliced chicken breast, fresh baby spinach, smoked Provolone, fresh mozzarella, freshly cut Roma tomatoes, roasted garlic, Romano, olive oil (instead of red sauce).</div>
</div>
<!-- END CHICKEN SPINACH MOZZARELLA --><!-- CLASSIC TRIO -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Classic-Trio-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Classic Trio&reg;</span><br />
Family recipe pepperoni and sausage, fresh mushrooms, smoked Provolone, Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- END CLASSIC TRIO --><!-- ULTIMATE 4 CHEESE -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Ultimate-4-Cheese-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Ultimate 4 Cheese</span><br />
Covered Edge to Edge&reg; with smoked Provolone, fresh mozzarella, Asiago, and Romano cheeses.</div>
</div>
<!-- END ULTIMATE 4 CHEESE --><!-- MARGHERITA -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2023/02/07/Margherita-With-Drizzle-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Margherita</span><br />
Fresh mozzarella and Asiago, smoked Provolone, freshly cut Roma tomatoes, basil, olive oil (instead of red sauce), balsamic drizzle.</div>
</div>
<!-- END MARGHERITA --><!-- CYO -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/CYO-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Create Your Own</span><br />
Create your own pizza with up to nine meat, veggie, and cheese toppings.</div>
</div>
<!-- END CYO --></div>

<div id="subs" style="margin: 40px 0 0 0; padding: 0; display: block; width: 100%;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Oven Baked Subs</h2>
</div>

<div class="menu-item-section"><!-- BIG DON -->
<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/27325156_Big-Don-Italian-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Big Don&reg;</span><br />
Oven baked with shaved ham, sliced salami, smoked Provolone, banana peppers, freshly cut Roma tomatoes, lettuce, and your choice of house Italian dressing or marinara sauce.</div>
</div>
<!-- END BIG DON --><!-- HOT CHICKEN -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/14643882_Hot-Chicken-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Hot Chicken</span><br />
Oven baked with crispy hot chicken, smoked Provolone cheese, jalape&ntilde;o peppers, dill pickles, ranch dressing.</div>
</div>
<!-- END HOT CHICKEN --><!-- FRESH VEGY -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2024/11/18/Fresh-Vegy-Menu-Image-mobile.jpeg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Fresh Vegy</span><br />
Oven baked with freshly cut Roma tomatoes, yellow onions and green peppers, fresh mushrooms, lettuce, banana peppers, smoked Provolone, house Italian dressing.</div>
</div>
<!-- END FRESH VEGY --><!-- CHICKEN BACON RANCH -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/44090963_Chicken-Bacon-Ranch-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Chicken Bacon Ranch</span><br />
Oven baked with chicken breast, hardwood smoked bacon, smoked Provolone, freshly cut Roma tomatoes, lettuce, ranch dressing.</div>
</div>
<!-- END CHICKEN BACON RANCH --><!-- MEATBALL -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Meatball-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Meatball</span><br />
Oven baked with family recipe meatballs, marinara sauce, smoked Provolone, Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- END MEATBALL --><!-- HAM & SMOKED PROVOLONE -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Ham-and-Smoked-Provolone-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Ham &amp; Smoked Provolone</span><br />
Oven baked with shaved ham, smoked Provolone, lettuce, freshly cut Roma tomatoes and yellow onions, house Italian dressing.</div>
</div>
<!-- END HAM & SMOKED PROVOLONE --></div>

<div class="grid--1" id="calzatos">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Calzatos</h2>
</div>

<div class="menu-item-section"><!-- CYO -->
<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2024/07/01/Calzato-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Create Your Own</span><br />
Handcrafted and filled with smoked Provolone cheese and marinara sauce, plus your choice of up to three toppings, and topped with Asiago, Romano. Served with marinara sauce for dipping.</div>
</div>
<!-- END CYO --></div>

<div id="appetizers" style="margin: 40px 0 0 0; padding: 0; display: block; width: 100%;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Appetizers</h2>
</div>

<div class="menu-item-section"><!-- ASIAGO -->
<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/24915223_Garlic-Asiago-Cheese-Bread-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Asiago Cheese Bread</span><br />
Oven-baked artisan pull-apart bread topped with Asiago and Romano, with marinara sauce for dipping.</div>
</div>
<!-- END ASIAGO --><!-- GARLIC ASIAGO -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/24915223_Garlic-Asiago-Cheese-Bread-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Garlic Asiago Cheese Bread</span><br />
Oven-baked artisan pull-apart bread topped with garlic, Asiago and Romano, with marinara sauce for dipping.</div>
</div>
<!-- END GARLIC ASIAGO --><!-- BREADSTICKS -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Italian-Garlic-Breadsticks-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Italian Garlic Breadsticks</span><br />
Warm garlic breadsticks with marinara sauce for dipping.</div>
</div>
<!-- END BREADSTICKS --><!-- MEATBALLS -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Meatball-Shareable-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Meatball Shareable</span><br />
Family recipe meatballs with marinara sauce, smoked Provolone and Romano.</div>
</div>
<!-- END MEATBALLS --></div>

<div id="wings" style="margin: 40px 0 0 0; padding: 0; display: block; width: 100%;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Wings</h2>
</div>

<div class="menu-item-section"><!-- TRADITIONAL WINGS -->
<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Traditional-Wings-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Traditional Sauced or Dry Rubbed Wings</span><br />
Oven roasted chicken wings hand-spun with your choice of Donatos wing sauce or dry rub.</div>
</div>
<!-- END TRADITIONAL WINGS --><!-- BONELESS WINGS -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/71513293_Boneless-Wings-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Boneless Wings</span><br />
Oven roasted and breaded all white meat chicken hand-spun with your choice of Donatos wing sauce.</div>
</div>
<!-- END BONELESS WINGS --></div>

<div id="salads" style="margin: 40px 0 0 0; padding: 0; display: block; width: 100%;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Salads</h2>
</div>

<div class="menu-item-section"><!-- ITALIAN SIDE SALAD -->
<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Italian-Side-Salad-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Italian Side Salad</span><br />
Banana peppers, family recipe pepperoni, freshly cut Roma tomatoes, smoked Provolone, Romano. Served with house Italian dressing. Made fresh daily.</div>
</div>
<!-- END ITALIAN SIDE SALAD --><!-- VERY VEGY SIDE SALAD -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2024/02/15/Very-Vegy-Salad-Mobile-Menu-Image.jpeg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Very Vegy Side Salad</span><br />
Freshly cut Roma tomatoes, freshly sliced green peppers and onion, green olives and smoked Provolone and Romano Cheeses. Made fresh daily.</div>
</div>
<!-- END VERY VEGY SIDE SALAD --><!-- ITALIAN CHEF SALAD -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/31871296_Italian-Chef-Salad-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Italian Chef</span><br />
Family recipe pepperoni, shaved ham, sliced salami, freshly cut Roma tomatoes, green peppers, banana peppers, black olives, smoked Provolone, Romano. Made fresh daily.</div>
</div>
<!-- END ITALIAN CHEF SALAD --><!-- CHICKEN HARVEST SALAD -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/41423285_Chicken-Harvest-Salad-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Chicken Harvest</span><br />
Chicken breast, hardwood smoked bacon, bleu cheese, honey roasted pecans, dried cranberries. Made fresh daily.</div>
</div>
<!-- END CHICKEN HARVEST SALAD --><!-- CHICKEN BACON RANCH SALAD -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/67426758_Chicken-Bacon-Ranch-Salad-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Chicken Bacon Ranch</span><br />
Chicken breast, hardwood smoked bacon, Asiago, Roma tomatoes, and served with ranch dressing. Made fresh daily.</div>
</div>
<!-- END CHICKEN BACON RANCH SALAD --><!-- ITALIAN GARDEN SALAD -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/79756994_Italian-Garden-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Italian Garden</span><br />
Freshly cut Roma tomatoes, and green peppers, banana peppers, smoked Provolone. Served with house Italian dressing. Serves 10 as a side.</div>
</div>
<!-- END ITALIAN GARDEN SALAD --></div>

<div id="desserts" style="margin: 40px 0 0 0; padding: 0; display: block; width: 100%;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Desserts</h2>

<div class="menu-item-section" style="margin-bottom: 40px;"><!-- PARTY TWISTS -->
<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Party-Twists-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Party Twists</span><br />
Sweet and delicious pull-apart twists, served warm, drizzled with vanilla icing, and topped with rainbow sprinkles. Serves 4.</div>
</div>
<!-- END PARTY TWISTS --><!-- CINNAMON BREAD -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/78242185_Cinnamon-Bread-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Cinnamon Bread</span><br />
Oven-baked artisan pull-apart bread topped with sweetened cinnamon spread, streusel topping, drizzled with vanilla icing.</div>
</div>
<!-- END CINNAMON BREAD --><!-- COOKIE -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Cookie-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Cheryl&#39;s&reg; Triple Chocolate Chunk Cookie</span><br />
Belgian bittersweet chocolate chips, semi-sweet chips and milk chocolate chips, pure cane brown sugar and pure Madagascar vanilla bean.</div>
</div>
<!-- END COOKIE --><!-- BROWNIE -->

<div class="global-menu-item">
<div style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block;"><img alt="" src="https://dbqmd35foa1f5.cloudfront.net//2022/09/12/Brownie-Menu-Image-Mobile.jpg" style="border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; display: block;" /></div>

<div class="global-menu-item-description" style="flex-grow: 1; display: inline-block; max-width: 390px;"><span class="interstate-bold">Cheryl&#39;s&reg; Fudge Brownie</span><br />
Individually wrapped brownie with real semi-sweet chocolate chips, unsweetened chocolate and cocoa.</div>
</div>
<!-- END BROWNIE --></div>
<style type="text/css">.anchor {margin: 0 0.7vw;}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.global-menu-item {border-radius: 8px; border: 2px solid #f0efed; min-width: 300px; align-items: center; grid-column: span 2;}
.global-menu-item:last-child:nth-child(3n - 1) {
  grid-column-end: -2;}
.global-menu-item:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n + 1) {
  grid-column-end: 4;}
/* Dealing with single orphan */
.global-menu-item:last-child:nth-child(3n - 2) {
  grid-column-end: 5;}
.menu-item-section{max-width: 1300px; 
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);}
}
.menu-item-section {margin: auto;}
.global-menu-item {border-radius: 8px; border: 2px solid #f0efed; min-width: 300px; align-items: center; justify-items: center; max-width: 95vw; margin: 5px auto;}
.global-menu-item-image {min-width: 300px; display: inline-block; }
.global-menu-item-description {margin: 10px;}
</style>
</div>


Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? Thanks!
